# Rails Form: Link to a named route rather than a url with query parameters

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

I have the following form:

```
<form action="<%= jobs_path %>" method="get" >
  <%= label_tag 'l', "I'm looking for a job in"%>
  <%= select_tag 'l',
    options_for_select(Job.areas.keys.map {|area| area.humanize.titlecase}, :selected => params[:l]),
    include_blank: "All Cities"
  %>
  and I'm interested in
  <%= text_field_tag 'q', nil, :placeholder => "Major or Interest...", :value => params[:q] || "" , :class =>"query" %>
  <%= submit_tag "Find Jobs", :name => nil, :class => "cta"%>
</form>
```

When you submit, this form currently creates links that look like `http://localhost:3000/jobs?l=Boston&q=assistant`.

But, I want the links to output like this:
`http://localhost:3000/jobs/l-Boston-q-assistant`

Right now, my `routes.rb` looks like this:

```
get "jobs/l-:l-q-:q", to: "jobs#index"
get "jobs/l-:l", to: "jobs#index"
get "jobs/q-:q", to: "jobs#index"

resources :jobs
```

This makes it so that links like `http://localhost:3000/jobs/l-Boston-q-assistant` do properly query, but if people use the search form on the page, it creates the query params version of the links.

How do I make it so that searches created with the form generate links like `http://localhost:3000/jobs/l-Boston-q-assistant`?

Comment: That seems very, em, *unconventional*.

Answer (score 0):

U probably want onsubmit function build string l-Boston-q-assistant from submited form elements and have route something

get 'jobs/:params', to: 'photos#show', params: /[a-zA-Z-]*/

then set location to jobs/generated string

then on controller u can split params into corresponding values